# Sql Server Full text use Contains reverse

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Normal usage of 'Contains '

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
DECLARE @SearchWord nvarchar(30)  
SET @SearchWord = N'performance'  
SELECT Description   
FROM Production.ProductDescription   
WHERE CONTAINS(Description, @SearchWord);
```

Can we run something like this, for searching Column inside 'search key'

```
SELECT Description   
FROM Production.ProductDescription   
WHERE CONTAINS(@SearchWord, Description);
```

Comment: I think that is not possible using `CONTAINS` because contains accepts column name as first parameter. Try using `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
DECLARE @SearchWord nvarchar(30)  
SET @SearchWord = N'performance'  
SELECT Description   
FROM Production.ProductDescription   
WHERE CHARINDEX(@SearchWord,Description)>0;
```

Using charindex text serch criteria  is faster than using like operator , if a millong of records

Comment: CHARINDEX does not have wildcard options like 'LIKE' or 'CONTAINS' hence this will not work